# Pagination's performance in AngularJS applications

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, pagination

I have written AngularJS application that lists a couple of thousands records from the database. Then I created front-end pagination using `limitTo` filter.

Thus I load all records at once and paginate them dynamically, so the result is:

```
DOM loading ~5s
page loading ~5.2s
```

DOM loading takes way too long, what can I do about it?

I was thinking about backend pagination instead, but then I couldn't do dynamic searching with all records, I couldn't do dynamic ordering, etc, because I'd slice the list on PHP level before javascript loads.

Any other solutions?

**view.tpl:**

```
some HTML
<script type="text/javascript">
   var data = {$data};
</script>
<script src="controller.js">
```

That's how I pass the variable from PHP controller to AngularJS controller. And thus the page source contains huge data array.

Comment: Do you have any sample code?

Comment: What do you mean by **paginate them dynamically** ? Are you playing with `ng-show/ng-hide` for paginition ?

Comment: Do you have `track by` in your repeater? http://blog.500tech.com/is-reactjs-fast/ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to format SQL result in back-end side (compact json response) ? Maybe you can use webstorage to stock all results and make once request to get it. 
https://github.com/fredricrylander/angular-webstorage

Comment: Check my edit. I am doing json encode on all data, so it can't be shorter, but it is still huge.

Answer (score 0):

DOM Loading time depends (or at least should) only on elements you show. If you have 5000 objects, but show only 10 - it should work fast.

- You should try using i.e. bootsrap pagination: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
- Or you can do it manually - using filter in html for big arrays is often bad idea, just create filteredArray in controller and update it when you need.

If you fix number of items on page (i.e. you want 200) making backend pagination will not improve your DOM render time.

Comment: I am using limitTo clausule, so it displays shortened data. I think the problem is that encoded data displays inside the page source.